# ELK Stack: Data not appearing in Kibana

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm new to the ELK stack so I'm not sure what the problem is. I have a configuration file (see screenshot, it's based on the elasticsearch tutorial):

**Configuration File**
[image]

Logstash is able to read the logs (it says Pipeline main started) but when the configuration file is run, elasticsearch doesn't react. I can search through the files 
[image]

However, when I open Kibana, it says no results found. I checked and made sure that my range is the full day.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In your Logstash configuration file you need to mention the hosts to which data is being stored (localhost:9200) and specify the index in which data will be stored.

Comment: @YuvrajGupta No, by default, it will try localhost:9200, with "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" as an index name (cf [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index)).
So you can keep the empty configuration.

Comment: I think it's a problem with Kibana, since your data is in the cluster. 
Are you sure about the range?

Comment: Another possible origin for you problem is the index pattern in Kibana, which is not configured on the right index. You should check if it's logstash-*

Comment: Ohh okay thanks @baudsp. I realized that the problem is that elasticsearch isn't indexing. Not sure how I can go about tackling this though...

Comment: To check if you have data in ES, you can use the search as you did in your screenshot.
To check if your log do not go from logstash to elasticsearch, you have to take a look at the output of your logstash instance (since you have the stdout output in your configuration).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I talked to the people at ELK and we figured it out, logstash wasn`t able to access my files for some reason so when I moved them to a different directory it was fine