# Kibana (ELK stack) dose not load the indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have installed an ELK stack. My elasticsearch disk was full, so I’ve changed the path.data parameter of elasticsearch.yml to point to a new disk. (The permissions of the new disk are correctly set,  ES is up and running, and I see the data is loaded to ES (collected in the new disk), so logstash is able to collect and send the data, When I query ES to list the indices(GET _cat/indices?v), I can see the indices are all listed , but the kibana web interface does not show any index which I can choose as the default one, so I get the error "No default index pattern. You must select or create one to continue.", but when I was using the old disk, it could automatically list all the available indices that I can choose from them. what should I do?

My problem is different from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932373/elk-stack-data-not-appearing-in-kibana) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722972/why-are-there-no-logstash-indexes-in-kibana), because es can list the indices. I only found [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/adding-more-path-data-folders-and-cluster-becomes-red/32990/14) related question, but it does not provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that Kibana is connected to your ES cluster after the change?
Can you share your kibana.yml and elasticsearch.yml as well as logstash.yml?

What you can try is to attempt reindexing your data on elasticsearch:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "your_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "your_new_index"
  }
}
```